# Multiple custom domains to specific version of Google App Engine app

Tags: google-app-engine

Let's say I have `myapp.appspot.com` and two custom domains respectively called `foo.com` and `bar.com`. How do I configure Google App Engine (GAE) such that:

> (www.)foo.com -> *foo*.myapp.appspot.com
>
> (www.)bar.com -> *bar*.myapp.appspot.com
>
> (www.)foo.com -> myapp.appspot.com (default version)

I'm reading https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain but I still don't understand how to configure it. I get the impression that GAE only supports wildcard for one custom domain e.g. `**.foo.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do that directly, as you associate your custom domain with an App ID rather than the App URL.

I guess you could map both foo.com and bar.com to your App ID, then in the default version of your App Engine parse the URL, and redirect accordingly, but it's not a great solution as you would be redirecting from your custom domain back to appspot.com domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can route using the [dispatch file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/how-requests-are-routed) (`dispatch.yaml`).

This [blog post](https://realguess.net/2015/09/24/add-a-custom-domain-to-the-specific-module-of-google-app-engine-managed-vms/) gave me the necessary info, and I imagine for the case of needing to map multiple domains to different modules would require a `dispatch.yaml` something like this:

```
# Dispatch
# ========
---
dispatch:
  - url: 'foo.com/*'
    module: foo
  - url: 'bar.com/*'
    module: bar
```

Don't forget to add the custom domains as well as SSL certs in the App Engine console.

Comment: this will only work on subdomains and main domain need to be the same. You can route to foo.example.com and bar.example.com but not on foo.com and bar.com