# Multitenant application domain names configurations in app engine

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, django-rest-framework, dns, googledns

I have developed a multitenant application in Google App Engine using Django Rest Framework(django-tenant-schemas) with Angular Front end as a Software As A Service Platform. I have purchased domain names locally and want to map several domain names to app engine resources so that if a client enters his domain url angular gets the url and retrieves content from its database schema.
I have configured only one domain name and I need to add other domain's. Is there a way I can configure all the domains to point to the same resources on the app engine

Answer (score 0):

For a multitenant application, you can use the dispatch.yaml configuration file, which allows you to override routing rules. You can use the dispatch.yaml to send incoming requests to a specific service (formerly known as modules) based on the path or hostname in the URL. Related detail may be gathered from the [dispatch.yaml Configuration File](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml) page.

You may check replies to the [Multiple custom domains to specific version of Google App Engine app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288424/multiple-custom-domains-to-specific-version-of-google-app-engine-app) question, and referenced page [Add a Custom Domain to the Specific Module of Google App Engine Managed VMs](https://realguess.net/2015/09/24/add-a-custom-domain-to-the-specific-module-of-google-app-engine-managed-vms/).